# Receiving user defined Object over TCP with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, tcp

I'm developing a client/server application that uses TCP connection. I need to send a user defined object from server to client. everything is working fine until the client receives the object, it throws the ClassNotFoundException even though the class is on both sides and I cast it, and it is Serializable.

The exception at client side is:

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jggserver.Question
```

I don't know why the client is casting using the server package. (they are different projects).

here is the code at client side, where the exception is:

```
    q = (Question) clientInputStream.readObject();
```

code at server side:

```
    serverOutputStream.writeObject(question);
```

Although I went through several tutorials and they do the exact thing.

I appreciate any help.

---

COMMENTS:

user1697575, both programs are on the same computer and same IDE (netbeans).

- I don't know about the TCP payload, I will search about it.
- I create the class on the server then refactor it on the client, I don't know if it's the correct way or not.
- I can't use RMI because I'm asked to specifically use this way to implement my project.

many thanks.

---

SOLVED: I created a separate package and added Question class to it, then I included this package in the server and the client programs.

thank you all guys, specially Juan.

Comment: does you client package contain the file **jggserver\Question.class**?

Comment: Blip, No the client contains the JGG.Question class which is the client program. should I include jggserver.Question? and delete the Question class from the client program? Thanks.

Comment: since the server is sending an instance of  jggserver.Question where as your client is trying to cast it as jgg.Question. These are basically 2 different classes in the perspective of JVM though the code inside may be the same.

Comment: you are right, but how to fix it? thats my question :D

Comment: You are passing the class `Question` in input and output streams so I assume that you have implemented `Serializable` interface in your `Question` class. Have you defined the `serialVersionUID` for the class?

Comment: Yes class Question implements Serializable, but I don't know about serialVersionUID, does it have something to do with this? because they didn't mention it in the all tutorials. I'm going to search about it though.

Comment: SerialVersionUID would cause a different error. Solve this problem first.

Comment: @EJP My first comment was about the problem OP was facing. And In my second comment itself I have state the details of the problem. This is also the same thing that you have stated in your answer.

Comment: @Blip My comment is addressed to the OP. I have no idea why you are addressing me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is in your question, here **"I don't know why the client is casting using the server package. (they are different projects)."**.

If packages on server and client are different, is impossible that standard serialisation system works.

You need create a class that is present is both projects with same name and package, really "same code".

Answer (score 0):

There are many check points to consider:

- JVM version on client and server
- TCP bytes payload check to see if they aren't get corrupted/translated
- Class versions loaded on the client and server

Also out of curiosity, why don't you use a robust [RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/) standard framework that taking care of many things for you?

Comment: Not one of these can cause a `ClassNotFoundException.`

Answer (score 0):

The class is *not* present on both sides. That's what the exception is telling you. It has to be the same class name, in the same package.